# Which library should be used to connect to AWS ElastiCache clusters?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I found two different AWS libraries to connect to [ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/):

- **AmazonElastiCacheClusterClient-1.0.jar**: This can be downloaded through the ElastiCache console as described in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoDiscovery.html#AutoDiscovery.ClusterClient). I have not found this as a publicly hosted Maven artifact. But given that this hasn't been changed in [in two years](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-elasticache-cluster-client-memcached-for-java) I am not sure if it's still the recommended library.
- **com.amazonaws:elasticache-java-cluster-client:1.0.61.0**: This was released in Feb 2014 and is a publicly available Maven artifact.

*Should the AWS docs be updated to reference com.amazonaws:elasticache-java-cluster-client:1.0.61.0 instead?*

I would like to take advantage of the [Node Auto Discovery](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoDiscovery.html) and thought that only the ElastiCache libraries support it.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon ElastiCache support Memcached and Redis protocols so any client that works with Memcached and Redis can be used.

Comment: Is that true even if I want to take advantage of the node auto discovery?